# Reading info.plist: inferred to have type AnyObject which may be unexpected

Tags: ios, swift, casting, info.plist

I inserted an `integer` in my `info.plist` file and, clearly, I'd like to retrieve it from my Swift `UIViewController`. The code is very simple:

```
class MyController: UIViewController {

    private let value: Int

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        if let info = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("v"){
            value = info.integerValue
        }else{
            value = 0
        }

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    //other auto-generated-methods
    //...

}
```

The function `objectForInfoDictionaryKey` returns an `AnyObject?` optional and I'm ok with this. But the compiler says to me that

> Constant "info" inferred to have type AnyObject which may be
>   unexpected

How can I solve this warning and why should I worry about the fact that the function returns an AnyObject? <-- this is a question mark... lol

Even if it returns an AnyObject I can downcast it if the object is not `nil`. I don't understand why the compiler complains about this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Xcode generally warns about variables which are *inferred* as `AnyObject` or
`AnyObject?`. You can add a type annotation (as Xcode suggests) to silence the warning:

```
if let info : AnyObject = ...
```

I can only speculate *why* Xcode behaves like this, but one reason could
be that you are "forced" to be aware that `info` might be of *any* object type
and not perhaps the one that you expect.

So even if `info.integerValue` *compiles*,
it  may crash at runtime if the object is not of
the expected type. In your case, if the dictionary value is not a `NSNumber` or `NSString`
then `info.integerValue` with throw an exception.

The safe way is to do an optional cast:

```
if let info = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("v") as? NSNumber {
    value = info.integerValue
} else {
    value = 0
}
```

Do to the automatic re-mapping between `NSNumber` and `Int` you can write that also as

```
if let info = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("v") as? Int {
    value = info
} else {
    value = 0
}
```

Or as a one-liner using the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
let value = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("v") as? Int ?? 0
```

Comment: Perfect. I was searching for your second solution, but the third one is very clear. Thank you.